# Does the Apple Healthkit store a unique identifier (UUID) developers can retrieve?

Tags: ios, uuid, healthkit, researchkit, carekit

Is there a unique identifier like a UUID attached to a Apple HealthKit, ResearchKit, or CareKit instance that would allow developers to know if the same user has multiple iPhones? Is there something that links a users healthKit to their iCloud account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not enable you to identify the user across devices.